# Using self in python, outside of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, self

I am a bit unsure how to use self outside of a class. A lot of built in methods in python use self as a parameter and there is no need for you to declare the class; For example, you can use the `string.upper()` command to capitalize each letter without needing to tell python which class to use. In case I'm not explaining myself well, I have included what my code looks like below.

```
def ispalendrome(self): return self == self[::-1]

largestProd = 999**2
largest5Palendromes = []
while len(largest5Palendromes) <= 5:
    if str(largestProd).ispalendrome(): largest5Palendromes.append(largestProd)
    largestProd -= 1
print largest5Palendromes
```

Note: I understand there are other ways of accomplishing this task, but I would like to know if this is possible. TYVM.

Comment: You mean you want to know if you can add a new method to the `str()` type. The answer is: no, not directly, you'd have to subclass.

Comment: What exactly is the problem or doesn't work here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters well he could use https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit ... but just cause you can does not mean you should

Comment: @JoranBeasley: whohoo, didn't know about that project. Yup, still not something I'd actually use, but cool.

Answer (score 5):

using https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse
def ispalendrome(self): #note that self is really just a variable name ... it doent have to be named self
    return self == self[::-1]
curse(str, "ispalendrome",ispalendrome)

"hello".ispalendrome()
```

**note that just because you can does not mean its a good idea**

alternatively it is much better to just do

```
def ispalendrome(a_string):
    return a_string == a_string[::-1]

ispalendrome("hello")
```

Comment: It's called "curse" for a reason!

Comment: should I make that disclaimer bolded? :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley You might want to take a look at the new `DynamicClassAttribute` in 3.4. That is _really_ evil.

Answer (score 3):

It feels like you want to monkey patch a method onto this. If so, then welcome to the dark side young one. Let us begin the cursed ritual. In essence you want to monkey patch. All we need is a little monkey blood. Just kidding. We need `type.MethodType`. But note, that you cannot monkey patch stdlib types:

```
>>> from types import MethodType
>>> def palindrome(self): return self == self[::-1]
...
>>> str.palindrome = MethodType(palindrome, str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

But that won't stop you from causing havoc in other classes:

```
>>> class String(object):
...     def __init__(self, done):
...         self.done = done
...
...
...
>>> s = String("stanley yelnats")
>>> def palindrome(self): return self.done[::-1]
>>> s.palindrome = MethodType(palindrome, s)
>>> s.palindrome()
'stanley yelnats'
```

You see how easy that was? But we're just getting started. This is just a mere instance lets kill a `class` now shall we? The next part will get you laughing maniacally:

```
>>> from types import DynamicClassAttribute
>>> class String(object):
...     def __init__(self, done):
...         self.done = done
...
...
...
>>> s = String("cheese")
>>> def palindrome(self): return self.done[::-1];
...
>>> String.palindrome = DynamicClassAttribute(palindrome)
>>> s.palindrome
'eseehc'
```

After this, if you do not feel evil. Then you must come over to my evil lair, where I shall show you more evil tricks and share *cookies*.

Answer (score 2):

Self has no special meaning - it is just a variable name. Its use in classes is merely conventional (so it may be confusing to use it elsewhere).

You can, however, set the properties of a class after-the-fact, and these could be class methods or instance methods (the latter with "self" by convention). This will NOT work with the built-in classes like `str`, though [edit: so you'd have to "curse" or subclass, see other answer]

Answer (score 2):

In

```
def ispalendrome(self)
```

there's no need to name the parameter `self` (indeed, it's a bit misleading), as this isn't an instance method. I would call it `s` (for string):

```
def is_palindrome(s):
```

What you may be referring to is the use of bound methods on the class, where:

```
an_instance = TheClass()
an_instance.instance_method() # self is passed implicitly
```

is equivalent to:

```
an_instance = TheClass()
TheClass.instance_method(an_instance) # self is passed explicitly
```

In this particular case, for example:

```
>>> "foo".upper()
'FOO'
>>> str.upper("foo")
'FOO'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python the first argument to a class method is the object instance itself, by convention it is called `self`. You should prevent using `self` for other purposes.

To explain it more detailed:

If you have a class

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1
```

and you make an instance of it:

```
a = A()
```

this calls the **init** method and the parameter self if filled with a fresh object. Then `self.b = 1` is called and add the attribute `b` to the new object. This object is then going to become knows as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

"self" is the name of the first parameter to a function - like any parameter, it has no meaning outside of that function. What it corresponds to is the object on which that function is called.